ArcGIS REST Server login/password
I can't make the REST server layer remember the password and login. With WMS its no problem but with the REST layer its not working and I have to repeat login/password every time I start QGIS. Is there anything that is different?
edit:Yes I can see login/password when I open the connection for editing. BUT I can't add that layer if I have answered "ignore" when opening the project and I cant add the login/password directly in properties in the ignored layer

Do you mean that you have saved the username and password when you created a new ArcGIS REST Server connection for QGIS, but QGIS does not remember them? Do you see the saved username/password when you open the connection for editing?

You have a tag for ArcGIS Pro but make no mention of using that desktop software in your question body so I'm removing it.

Use the 'Configurations' section under 'Authentication' to store the login information. This can be accessed either by editing the connection or going to: Settings - options - Authentication.
I always use 'Basic Authentication', but there are many options to choose from. 

thanks i just used the tab basic. That tab work in WMS but REST is maybe demanding to add an authentication
